# Smartphone app to sound an alarm when a specific email is received

Tags: monitoring, alerts, smartphone

This may be borderline Server Fault, so I'm cool if it's decided this question is migrated elsewhere.

As a sysadmin, I am responsible for responding to any monitoring alerts which occur out of hours. I have a company issue BlackBerry, so if a monitoring alert is sent, I can be notified. This is great .. provided I'm not in another room or asleep. Yes, it makes a noise when an email is received, but if I miss that little noise that lasts about 2 seconds, I've missed the alert.

What I'm looking for is an app (paid for isn't a problem) which can sound an alarm when an email is received that matches certain criteria that *does not stop* until I dismiss it.

Criteria would be any of the following (bonus points if I can mix and match criteria)

- Sender address
- Message subject
- Recipients

This is primarily for a BlackBerry, but apps for other smartphones might be beneficial to the greater community.

Comment: I don't know if there's an equivalent for BlackBerry, but this sounds like something for Tasker for Android. I used to do stuff like this but with text messages.

Comment: Don't know about the Blackberry, but I use the combination of Missed Reminder (which will keep sounding an alert when I get an SMS), LockRinger (which makes sure that my ringer is never accidentally set too softly), and Google Voice for getting non-work SMSes.  nagios sends messages directly to my phone via SMS, which Missed Reminder will sound an alert for every 30 seconds (configurable).  For non-emergency SMSes, I give my Google Voice number, which uses a different ringer setting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Blackberry, but on Android you can use ["Wake Me Up! Smart Alarm"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chlochlo.adaptativealarm) and Tasker. This is the easiest solution I found and it requires no coding.

First, open the Wake Me Up! app and create a Tasker Alarm:
1) New alarm > Trigger:Tasker > Save

Next, we'll make the event:
1) Go to Tasker and create an event triggered by a notification (Event>UI>Notification).
2) For the Owner Application select your email app (in my case it was Gmail)
3) For the Title enter whatever the title of the notification is (in my case it was TradingView).

Lastly, we'll make the task:
1) Name your Task "Alarm" or whatever.
2) Hit the plus sign to add an action.
3) Select Plugin > Wake me up! > Trigger an alarm > Configure > Select the Tasker alarm you created in the first step.

All done. You should now have an alarm that's triggered by an email notification.

Answer (score 1):

> where is my droid

its for the android and can turn on the volume to full on a keyword sent over sms. Most carriers provide a callNumber@domain.com email which will sms your phone. You can have your alert be nagios.

**Website:** http://sites.google.com/site/alienmanfc6/wheresmyandroid

Answer (score 0):

As most people have stated, there are not many options for blackberry, but I recommend having the email send several times, and there should be a option in settings to make the alert longer and louder as I rememberer as I now have a Droid.

Comment: More rings for emails will certainly give me more chance if I'm asleep, but it's not foolproof - it really needs a constant alarm to wake me up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using IFTTT to parse your email look for keywords in subject our from address. as far an action goes it can call your phone or set an IF notification

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is email - it really isn't meant for that and it does it very poorly. There are services such as PagerDuty that you can send your alerts to instead and you can have them actually phone you (it will keep trying acc. to how you specify) and you can acknowledge from the phones keypad. Email is the 90's  way ... SMS is also terrible for alerts.